# Android genymotion issues

Tags: android, adb, genymotion

I am trying to make a simple map and I am using genymotion as a virtual device. When I am running my program I am getting an error which says: The app won't run unless you update google play services. when I am trying to update nothing happens. Anyone has any idea of what can I do so I can display the map on the atb?

Answer (score 0):

Basically i solved it thanks for your advice. If you want to use google maps on an emulator such as genymotion you need to install google play on the emulator. For me all the emulator that android provides me on eclipse didnt work so i found genymotion to be the best one. Cheers